# Getting Ink Serialization Format opertion failed message after trying to show stored signature in MySql database

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

Any help appreciated.

Code to save in MySQL - seems to work fine.  The error is occurring when I read the blob back and try to convert it back to the signature which was saved from a WPF inkcanvas.  Getting occurs right after `ms.potion = 0`.

```
if (MyInkCanvas.Strokes.Count > 0)
{
    byte[] signature;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        MyInkCanvas.Strokes.Save(ms);
        signature = ms.ToArray();
    }


    string myConnection = Global.mySqlconn;
    string updater = Global.fname + " " + Global.lname;
    string sql002 = "INSERT INTO database.signature (signature_type, signature_test_id, signature, signature_updater_name, signature_cdate) ";
    sql002 += "Values ('" + svtype + "', " + tid + ", '" + signature + "', '" + updater + "', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) ";

    // MessageBox.Show(sql002);

    MySqlConnection conn2 = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
    MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand();
    cmd2.CommandText = sql002;
    cmd2.Connection = conn2;
    conn2.Open();
    try
    {
        int aff = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn2.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error encountered during INSERT of signature operation - call operations - " + sql002);
        return;
    }
```

Code to read and display from MySQL database - can read but cannot serialize.

```
try
    {
        //download the image

        byte[] signature = Signature.DownloadImage(tid, svtype);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(signature))
        {
            ms.Position = 0;
            StrokeCollection strokes = new StrokeCollection(ms);
            MyInkCanvas.Strokes = strokes;
            ms.Close();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}
        // <summary>
/// Downloads a byte[] from a BLOB
/// </summary>
/// <param name="connectionString"></param>
/// <returns>The BLOB as byte[]</returns>
public static byte[] DownloadImage(string stid, string stype)
{
    try
    {
        string myConnection = Global.mySqlconn;
        string sql = "SELECT signature from database.signature where signature_test_id = " + stid + " and signature_type = '" + stype + "'";
        MessageBox.Show(sql);
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);


        conn.Open();
        byte[] barrImg = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar() as byte[];
        conn.Close();

        return barrImg;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```